# how to grab specific data from an api call in RXJava

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, rx-java, rx-java2

Hi I have a question I want to grab specific data about the title and product id from a list in a data class as shown what should I need to write in the shared preference call to grab this data I have shown in the image.

The image I have selected is from the debug when pulling the information out of the function in my viewmodel.[image]

I want to try get productid and title from this "it.data" but data is a

```
var data: List<Data>,
```

My Viewmodel

```
class HomeFragmentVM(

    private val spManager: SPManager,
    private val repository: Repository
) : AbstractViewModel() {

    private val washingMachine = MutableLiveData<Post>()


    fun getWashingMachines() {
        launch {
            repository.getPost()
                .doOnSubscribe {

                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                                                                                                                  
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    washingMachine.value = it
//                    spManager.saveTitleID()
                }, {
                })
        }
    }
```

my Data data class

```
data class Data (
    @SerializedName("productId")
    var productid: Int,
    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String?,

)
```

My post data class

```
data class Post(
    @SerializedName("products")
    var data: List<Data>
)
```

So Im wondering how can i grab the productid and title and to save it via sharedpreference manager Many Thanks :)

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are facing; you aren't able to do this?
`it.data.forEach {
            //Save it individually
            //it.productid
            //it.title
        }`

Comment: I/System.out: null
gives me a null when i try to subscribe like this  
```
                .subscribe({
                    it.data.forEach {
                        it.productid
                        it.title
                    }
                    washingMachine.value = it
                    spManager.saveTitleID(washingMachine.toString())

                }, {
                })
```

Comment: Just to be sure, please check if key is `products` not `data`.

Comment: 100% sure, it says {"showInStockOnly":true,"isPersonalised":false,"products and etc...":}